# AngularJS + OAuth

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I'm trying to write a login solution for my Angular App, 
This means to allow the user to connect via Facebook/Google/Twitter or Register normally. 
I found [Angular-OAuth](https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth) to be useful, but it didn't seem to work with Facebook (or Twitter).

Anyone knows of an all-inclusive solution for this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look at [oauth.io](https://oauth.io)

- Easy implementation in Javascript
- 80+ OAuth providers
- Fast & secure

Comment: is this still the best solution for angular apps?

Comment: OAuth.io has a large freemium model (up to 1000 monthly users) and an opensource version available on Github: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd

Comment: Any idea on how to call twitter authorize instead of autenticate using Oauth.io?

Comment: @clopez https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter.
But you can't do it using angular-js only, you need to have a backend as it require to send via HTTP your API keys (with the secret key), the signature and others OAuth parameters which have to stay secret.

Comment: As I've said before, of course, the service is not totaly free, the company need money somewhere to continue further. But, we developed the opensource version oauthd (https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd) which is completely free, the core is exactly the same than oauth.io. The mentality behind oauth.io is to publish everything in opensource license, so if you have a server, it is free.

Answer (score 54):

Here is a simple example using just redirects with angular js

Here is how to redirect to authentication

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.login=function() {
        var client_id="your client id";
        var scope="email";
        var redirect_uri="http://localhost:9000";
        var response_type="token";
        var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope="+scope+"&client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+
        "&response_type="+response_type;
        window.location.replace(url);
    };
  });
```

Here is how to handle the redirect after authentication

```
angular
  .module('angularoauthexampleApp', [
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
        template: '',
        controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
          var hash = $location.path().substr(1);

          var splitted = hash.split('&');
          var params = {};

          for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
            var key    = param[0];
            var value  = param[1];
            params[key] = value;
            $rootScope.accesstoken=params;
          }
          $location.path("/about");
        }
      })
  });
```

More complete information here http://anandsekar.github.io/oauth2-with-angularjs/

Comment: why is this not the chosen answer?

Comment: I agree, this is the most complete answer

Comment: How different part of application get that user is authorized?

Comment: Won't this cause a brand new instance of your angular application to be bootstrapped upon the browser receiving the redirect from the OAuth server?

Answer (score 13):

There is a Free-Open-Source alternative to the freemium [oauth.io](http://oauth.io): [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/)

Comment: OAuth.io is also opensource with his OAuth deamon: github.com/oauth-io/oauthd ;)

Comment: But that's only the OAuth provider (server), not the js client I think.

Comment: All client are available on github:
[js](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js), [ios](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios), [android](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-android), [phonegap](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap), [flex](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-flex), [php](https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-php), [node.js](https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-node) and more are coming). You can configure them to work with oauthd instead of oauth.io

Comment: btw oauthd is not an OAuth provider but the clone of OAuth.io made by the OAuth.io team in opensource (the core - The API Key manager / OAuth process flow / proxy the API call for OAuth1 / user unification etc...).

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/wiki/Login-with-OAuth-2.0) project on Github. I'm just getting started with it, it seems promising.

It uses JSON Web Tokens, and allows login with: email+password, Facebook, Twitter, Google, and any other OAuth 1.0/2.0 provider.

The client side code works out the box, you'll have to implement the server side yourself. There are good descriptions of the work flows and code examples for many server side languages.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add some comment and sample Angular code for the [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io) solution mentioned above.
As the founder stated, it is a paid service but it has 2 main benefits I believe:

- It provides a consistent way to connect to any OAuth provider be it Facebook, Twitter, etc., i.e.,it hides all the peculiarities of each OAuth provider implementation.
- It enables you implement OAuth social buttons using only front-end code.

The front-end code is also rather simple. I took this from [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/0qa_kw/create-a-social-login-button-any-oauth-provider-using-angular-js).

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
  // return the global native browser window object
  return window;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const oauthScript = document.createElement('script');
    oauthScript.src = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/oauth-io/oauth-js/c5af4519/dist/oauth.js';

    document.body.appendChild(oauthScript);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    // Prevents page reload
    e.preventDefault();

    // Initializes OAuth.io with API key
    // Sign-up an account to get one
    _window().OAuth.initialize('YOUR OAUTH.IO PUBLIC KEY');

    // Popup Github and ask for authorization
    _window().OAuth.popup('github').then((provider) => {

      // Prompts 'welcome' message with User's name on successful login
      // Check console logs for additional User info
      provider.me().then((data) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
        alert('Welcome ' + data.name + '!');
      });

      // You can also call Github's API using .get()
      provider.get('/user').then((data) => {
        console.log('self data:', data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```